# Swift - check if login succeeded (post request)

Tags: swift

I have implemented NSURLConnectionDelegate, and it seems I have successfully sent a post request which in theory should log me on.

```
var url = NSURL(string:"https://www.test.com/signin.html")
var request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: url)
request.HTTPMethod = "POST"
var dataString = postString
let data = (dataString as NSString).dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)
request.HTTPBody = data
var connection = NSURLConnection(request: request, delegate: self, startImmediately: false)
println("sending request...")
connection.start()
```

I print the data here after the post request:

```
func connectionDidFinishLoading(connection: NSURLConnection) {
// The request is complete and data has been received
// You can parse the stuff in your instance variable now
print ("\(responseData)")
}
```

And that gives me a some html code and other stuff back in hex.
How can I check whether my login has succeeded? Ultimately I want to navigate straight to a certain part of the website and parse a document.

EDIT: I currently receive back status code 200 for both correct and incorrect credentials, so somethings definitely not right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It ultimately completely depends on your web API. The convention is to use the status code of the response. A status code of 200 (OK) would indicate that the login was successful. The API should then return a 401 (Unauthorized) if login was not successful.

`NSURLResponse` has a `statusCode` property

Comment: except that I don't seem to have permission to go to the next link, and the returned data after the post request is the original login page again, which makes me think its failed?

Comment: I don't think this is good solution 200 can be returned in many cases not just successful login.

Comment: If you are getting a 200 response for incorrect logins and/or login is not working on that server, you need to fix that / have it fixed. This is the way the web works. The server you are logging into should be designed in such a way that the only possible way to get a 200 from the login endpoint is with valid credentials. That is basic web API design.